# ACF Front end field checkbox with: Mark as Read

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have to create a field in the front end for each subscriber that can mark the post as read.

I want to set a flag, so a user will know which post he has read and which he has not read.

Perhaps the best solution for me is to associate this flag for each user id and store everything in the post object. Is it possibile?

So I the following basic code, with a checkbox field:

```
<?php
     $args = array( 
      'field_groups' => array( 1152 ),
     );
     acf_form( $args ); 
?>
```

In functions.php:

```
function my_acf_save_post($post_id) {
  wp_update_post();
  add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
}
```

Now I can update the field in the front end post, but how can I associate this field for each subscriber so that each account can mark the post?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to count the number of times the post has been read or are you setting a flag, so a user will know, they personally have already seen the post? you will need to decide whether you are storing data for each user (i.e. the user account id) on the post object, or storing read post IDs on the user table. Please provide some more context to help us better answer the question.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified my question: "I want to set a flag, so a user will know which post he has read and which he has not read.
Perhaps the best solution for me is to associate this flag for each user id and store everything in the post object. Is it possibile?"